# How to find all occurrences of a word or a character and edit in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to find all occurrences of word or a character and select them once and edit using multi cursor in visual studio code?

I have list of users and need to add domain before names.

I have:

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

I want :

```
domain\abc
domain\pqr
domain\xyz
```

I want to search for a new line character which will take me to the end of the each user name then by pressing home button I should reach to the beginning of each user where I will type "domain\" and it will modify each user at once.

I was able to do this in sublime text 3 by find all feature which provides multi cursor at each occurrence of character.

Is there any way to do the same in VS code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this doesn't involve searching for newlines but rather by

1. Making a selection (Such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Add cursor to all lines of the selection (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
3. Pressing home (<kbd>Home</kbd>)

Comment: crtl + shift + alt + arrow up or down also works, but your answer is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use search and replace with a simple regular expression.

Search for: `^(.+)$`

Replace with: `domain\\$1`

Make sure to enable regular expressions (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).